# Pivot in T-SQL throws syntax error

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

I am trying to do a pivot in T-SQL that return `SUM(INVOICE_AMOUNT)` for 2015 and 2016 for each `CUST_ID`.

But the SQL I'm using throws an error:

> Incorrect syntax near '('

and I can't identify the syntax error. Could someone advise what's wrong with it?

```
SELECT 
    H.CUST_ID, [2015], [2016]
FROM
    (SELECT  
         H.INVOICE_AMOUNT, YEAR(H.INVOICE_DT)
     FROM 
         BILLING_HEADER H) p
PIVOT
    SUM(H.INVOICE_AMOUNT) FOR YEAR(INVOICE_DT) IN ([2015], [2016])) AS pvt
```

The `Year(INVOICE_AMOUNT)` has static option of [2015] and [2016], so not sure what's wrong with the SQL..

Comment: Can you put `YEAR(INVOICE_DT)` after ·`FOR` keyword? I think only column can appear here. Give `YEAR(INVOICE_DT)` an alias and use that alias after `FOR`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks for pointing out "it needs an alias"... That's what I am missing. I've given alias to the columns and it works the trick! (without moving `YEAR(INVOICE_DT)` after the `FOR`.) Thanks for your comment and insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PIVOT` operator expects [column that contains the values that will become column headers](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) after `FOR` keyword. Give `YEAR(INVOICE_DT)` an alias and use that alias after `FOR`

```
SELECT H.CUST_ID, [2015], [2016]
FROM
(
    SELECT H.INVOICE_AMOUNT, YEAR(H.INVOICE_DT) AS INVOICE_YEAR
    FROM BILLING_HEADER H
) p
PIVOT
    SUM(H.INVOICE_AMOUNT)
    FOR INVOICE_YEAR in ([2015],[2016])
) as pvt
```

Essentially, PIVOT operator perform a `GROUP BY` operation, and it guesses which column should be put into `GROUP BY` clause by removing columns being used in `PIVOT` operator from source table column. Such guess doesn't work with function. See a little information at [TSQL - Looking for code clarification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443290/tsql-looking-for-code-clarification/39444111#39444111)